# SQL How would I select all rows between two dates?

Tags: sql, date, select

If had these employees with set onboard and removal dates in rows...

```
NAME ------- ONBOARD DATE ------- DEPARTURE DATE
Jon          10/10/2015           10/10/2016
Bob          4/11/2015            5/11/2015
Lucy         5/16/2015            12/16/2015
Jim          3/10/2014            8/8/2016
```

...and I wanted to select whoever's employment was valid on 5/28/2015, what would I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
select * from tablename
where '5/28/2015' between ONBOARD_DATE and DEPARTURE_DATE
```

(Not sure about the date literal... Depends on dbms used!)